# I need to choose the size of pizzas and also one count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help on hum Project. Add your functionality need to choose size and quantity of pizzas.

I did the base code with any agile web development with rails Book 4 but with some modifications .

The Running Project can be viewed here: http://aqueous-inlet-96557.herokuapp.com/
Please use hum mobile device paragraph open , STILL I did not like views for PCs.

The Project Code is here https://github.com/PetersonFonseca/7b

I am using this project as Weeks study , however I'm tangled up in this seethe days. All help is welcome Well . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

Start by updating your data model to take account of size and quantity.

Adding a size to a product can be achieved in different ways. One is to have a separate product for each size. This approach will require adding the size attribute to the product table with a migration. Alternatively look up sku, a common approach in retail for products which come in different sizes and colours.

You will also need to decide where in your data model you want to store the quantity. Possibly in line_item.

Once you have updated your data model to take account of these new attributes, you can them include them in the form to be stored.

Comment: I'm having trouble saving select_tag data. I do not know how to reference in store / id / orders

Comment: In fact I would like to understand how I can use a select for size and save this information in orders. For example size S, M, or G

Comment: Update your answer with the specific code. Its not good enough to post a link to your code, you have to show it, and be sure to format it properly, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks